# Find the PDF of Z where $Z = X^2 + Y^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, means, variance

$X$ and $Y$ are independent normal variable with zero mean and common variance $k$, Find the Probability Density of Function of $Z = X^2 + Y^2$? 
We can although find the PDF of a random variable if it is function of one random variable with know PDF, but how to calculate for $2$ variables. I was not able to proceed. How to use the given data of common variance?

Answer (score 1):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution

It's known as the Chi-squared distribution. The sum of squares of Gaussians is quite common so it is well studied. That's for zero mean and unit variance but to get a different variance it's just a scaling factor.